# Does all matter from which a black hole is formed, end up, infinitely stretched out on the radial space coordinate, and on a small time interval?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

As a previous question I asked is closed let me give it another try. In the comments on that question two different "views" popped up.(I don't know how to call it else, since I'm not sure what is actually the case)

The situation is as follows. Let's consider a collection of particles forming a black hole. Say a spherical cloud of dust. The cloud will contract and as we fall along with the dust particles the particles in our falling frame seem to contract angularly and expand radially while the clocks on each dust particle progress alike angularly but differently in the radial direction. Now it gets a bit tricky and I may be speculating here but that's exactly why I ask this question.

It seems to me that in the freely falling frame an even horizon is formed in the direction of the center of the cloud rushing outwardly. After we have passed the horizon (or when it passes ús) it takes a small proper time to reach te center which is actually infinitely far away.

Now, when inside the falling frame a small proper time has passed, the time that has passed in the surrounding universe may have passed millions of years, so all matter that will be part of the hole after the formation of the hole will be contained in the falling frame inside the horizon and on a small time-like interval. So I guess...

So in the freely falling frame an horizon  starts forming at the center spreading out, while this process seen in a faraway frame at rest seems to end at a growing horizon.

Now, my question. Can we say that in the freely falling frame, the entire formation of the hole looks like all matter that was, is and will be part of the hole, is stretched out infinitely in radial direction and and contained in a small amount of time only, while from the faraway outside, in a frame at rest, the process looks like all matter being compressed in a growing spherical Schwarzschild surface?

In other words, does all matter (point-like particles) entering a black hole's horizon, in it's entire history, as seen from a freely falling frame, end up stretched out infinitely on the radial coordinate and on a small time-like interval?

Comment: This Science Clic video may help - [Why Time and Space swap in a Black Hole](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc)

Comment: @mmesser314 Doesn't the swap occur for a faraway observer at rest only? How would this swap show itself if you actually fall in?

Comment: @safesphere Yes, that's what I say and ask.  But I mean, how does the space/time swap as seen in a faraway frame show itself in the falling frame? I can't see such a swap happening. The onjects seem to end up separated over space infinitely and spread in time only little.